# How To Generate Gaps For Missing Data

Tags: sql, join, left-join, gaps-and-islands

I have data that is structured as follows:

[image]

Using the following CTE:

```
WITH DateRange AS
(
SELECT CAST('2012-01-24 06:00' AS DATETIME) DateValue
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(mi, 1, DateValue)
FROM    DateRange   
WHERE   DATEADD(mi, 1, DateValue) <= '2012-01-24 12:00'
)
SELECT DateValue FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I have created a "Date Set" that look like this:

[image]

**The Issue Is:** There is some data in the original data-set that does not have a corresponding date in the CTE (In the provided example, 2012-01-24 6:00 is not present in the data).

For these missing data points, I would like to see "NULL" as their value. I thought I might be able to leverage the dates in the CTE I generated, but I'm not sure how I can do this.

I have tried something like this with no success:

```
SELECT C.DateValue, D.Value 
FROM myCTE C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN myData D ON C.DateValue = D.Date
ORDER BY C.DateValue ASC;
```

Comment: Your query looks fine - you've not taken anything out to simplify this before posting have you?

Comment: @SteveHomer: Not really. There are about 7 more columns in my data-set, but that's about it.

Comment: Any criteria on a field from the right side of the join (myData)?

Comment: @SteveHomer: Unfortunately not. The only additional columns deal with Data Validity and Location of Data Collection.

Comment: That's bizarre, I've just created the same structure and data here and it works as I'd expect. Not sure what to suggest to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate the issue you're seeing. I've created the query below and tested it and it works fine - can you test this in your environment?

```
Declare @var as Table (DateValue datetime)

Insert Into @var (DateValue) Values ('2012-01-24 06:01:00.000')
Insert Into @var (DateValue) Values ('2012-01-24 06:02:00.000')
Insert Into @var (DateValue) Values ('2012-01-24 06:03:00.000')

;WITH DateRange AS ( 
    SELECT CAST('2012-01-24 06:00' AS DATETIME) DateValue 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(mi, 1, DateValue) 
    FROM    DateRange    
    WHERE   DATEADD(mi, 1, DateValue) <= '2012-01-24 12:00' 
) 

SELECT dr.DateValue, v.DateValue
FROM DateRange dr
        Left Outer Join @var v On dr.DateValue = v.DateValue
Order By v.DateValue
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, not a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. The left join has nulls where the right-hand side is missing data; the left-hand side here is `myCTE`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. It generates NULL for any Date present in the Data-Set but not present in the CTE. I trying to get the opposite: NULL for any Date in the CTE that is not present in the Data-set.